# Import the selected Images from the gallery to your app

Tags: android, android-listview, android-gallery

I am using following code to select multiple images from the gallery

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 1);
```

This works fine and I can select multiple images from the gallery. But what I want to do now is to import all the selected images in our app and populate those images in the form of a ListView. Can anyone suggest anything that might help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After you copy the selected images, you will have to display them on a list view.

Some code example to import/copy the selected images can be found here : 
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/pick-image-from-galary-android-app/

The best documentation of Android to display images in a list view is here : http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html .